# How to trigger keypress event in React.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, dom-events

I'm new to React.js.
I'm trying to trigger keypress event for text div.

Here is text box code for which I want to execute keypress trigger.

```
<div id="test23" contenteditable="true" class="input" placeholder="type a message" data-reactid="137">Hii...</div>
```

and keypress method is:

```
onKeyPress: function(e) {
   return "Enter" == e.key ? "Enter key event triggered" : void 0)
}
```

I tried it with jQuery but I can't trigger it.

Here is my React code that I tried but its not working:

```
var event = new Event('keypress', {
 'keyCode' : 13,
 'which' : 13,
 'key' : 'Enter'
});
var node = document.getElementById('test23');
node.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you create a reference to the div, then you can trigger an event on it.  With hooks, you can use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).  Without hooks, you can use [`createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs).

**With hooks:**

```
function MyComponent() {
  const ref = useRef();

  // This is simply an example that demonstrates
  // how you can dispatch an event on the element.
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {
      key: 'Enter',
    }));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      id="test23"
      contentEditable={true}
      className="input"
      placeholder="type a message"
      data-reactid="137"
    />
  );
}
```

**Without hooks:**

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ref = React.createRef();
  }

  // This is simply an example that demonstrates
  // how you can dispatch an event on the element.
  triggerKeyPress() {
    this.ref.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {
      key: 'Enter',
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        ref={this.ref}
        id="test23"
        contentEditable={true}
        className="input"
        placeholder="type a message"
        data-reactid="137"
      />
    );
  }
}

el.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{'key':'a'}));
```

Comment: 'el' is not defined

Comment: ref does not have a method dispatchEvent

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create a keyboard event, you can make use of [KeyboradEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent) constructor.

An enter key event can be dispatched like:

```
const event = new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {
  key: 'enter',
});
console.log(event) // KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: false, key: "enter", code: "", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
```

FYI: The [react-keydown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-keydown) package is good for implementing keyboard navigation or other shortcuts.

Answer (score -4):

Test util [Simulate](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#simulate) is designed to trigger events during unit tests.